# Not receiving Products from function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working through the tutorial files in the book Pro Angular for a Store Front application. I am currently working on an administration section and am getting an error saying "Failed to load resources, cannot connect to the server". This is my rest.datasource.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Request, RequestMethod } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { Cart } from "./cart.model";
import { Order } from "./order.model";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

const PROTOCOL = "http";
const PORT = 3000;

@Injectable()
export class RestDataSource {
    baseUrl: string;
    auth_token: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.baseUrl = `${PROTOCOL}://${location.hostname}:${PORT}/`;
    }

    authenticate(user: string, pass: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.request(new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this.baseUrl + "login",
            body: { name: user, password: pass }
        })).map(response => {
            let r = response.json();
            this.auth_token = r.success ? r.token : null;
            return r.success;
        });
    }

    getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, "products");
    }

    saveProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, "products",
            product, true);
    }

    updateProduct(product): Observable<Product> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put,
            `products/${product.id}`, product, true);
    }

    deleteProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete,
            `products/${id}`, null, true);
    }

    getOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get,
            "orders", null, true);
    }

    deleteOrder(id: number): Observable<Order> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete,
            `orders/${id}`, null, true);
    }

    updateOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put,
            `orders/${order.id}`, order, true);
    }

    saveOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post,
            "orders", order);
    }

    private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod,
            url: string, body?: Product | Order, auth: boolean = false)
                : Observable<Product | Product[] | Order | Order[]> {

        let request = new Request({
            method: verb,
            url: this.baseUrl + url,
            body: body
        });
        if (auth && this.auth_token != null) {
            request.headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer<${this.auth_token}>`);
        }
        return this.http.request(request).map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

and here is my static.datasource.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Product } from "./product.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/from";
import { Order } from "./order.model";
@Injectable()
export class StaticDataSource {
    //Populate product fields with Inventory information
    private products: Product[] = [
       //products omitted for brevity
    ];
    getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return Observable.from([this.products]);
    }

    saveOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(order));
   return Observable.from([order]);
    }
}
```

I am following the tutorial exactly but for some reason the site falls apart now that I am on Chapter 9 creating the admin section. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was my mistake. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `@angular/http` is deprecated in favour of `@angular/common/http`; you should probably find a more up-to-date resource.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Hmm `this.baseUrl = \`${PROTOCOL}://${location.hostname}:${PORT}/\`;` did you define `location` anywhere?

Comment: Also, I would check the version of rxjs you are using. Iirc, rxjs 6 changed how operators work: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax